# Linux command to output each new process PID

Tags: linux, ps

Is there a linux command that will watch for new processes?

My goal in this is I want to see when a new `gulp` command is called, get the command line executed with something like `ps`, then filter it using `sed`.

The important part is the watching of new processes, since I can't look up a PID once it's finished.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the `auditd` subsystem to log the commands run on your system. It's hooked into the kernel, so it's very reliable to log everything that is executed.

My examples are on Fedora Linux, you might find small differences depending on your distro. (The `auditd` subsystem is quite complex, so it might be tricky to get this right.)

First check that you already have auditd installed and running, with:

```
$ systemctl status auditd.service
```

Then you can check which rules are loaded. By default, on Fedora, you get:

```
$ sudo auditctl -l
-a never,task
```

So we need to remove this "task" list (which suppresses syscalls) and add one that logs "execve" (which is the syscall that executes commands.)

```
$ sudo auditctl -d never,task
$ sudo auditctl -a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S execve
```

Once that is done, all commands will be logged to the audit system.

You can then search it, using the `ausearch` command. For instance, to find all executions that call "gulp", you can use:

```
$ sudo ausearch -c gulp
```

The output will be quite verbose... Focus on the type=EXECVE line. The arguments will be listed as `a0="gulp" a1="first_argument" a2="second_argument" ...`

If you get a long sequence of numbers instead of a quoted string, use `-i` to interpret it.

Logging every command that runs on your system can be very expensive and use a lot of diskspace! It's possible that it affects performance too. If you want to undo these changes, you can reload the default set of rules with this command:

```
$ sudo augenrules --load
```

You can also apply a filter to the logging rule, for instance to only log executions of /usr/bin/gulp:

```
$ sudo auditctl -a always,exit -F arch=b64 -F exe=/usr/bin/gulp -S execve
```

So, maybe this is overkill... But it's as reliable as it gets. I hope you can find your way through the `auditd` subsystem and that it gives you the information you're looking for!